# Google Analytics PDF reports not displaying data

Tags: pdf, google-analytics, report, analytics

Since a few days back our custom dashboard reports (scheduled e-mail PDFs) are not showing any data and the layout is broken.

There has not been any changes done to the dashboards and they’ve been working for months. When generating and sending the PDF reports manually they show up just fine.

The only difference in the reports is that a text that wasn't there before has been added: "All users on your account, regardless of permissions, will soon be able to see who else has access to that account. Learn More"

Please view attached screenshot (link).
[Screenshot of broken GA PDF report](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AHvU3.jpg)

Does anyone else have the same issue?
Has someone been able to fix this?

Cheers,
Thomas

Comment: I have the same exact problem. They've changed the navigation again and that is somehow messing with the PDF report template. I've sent feedback via GA but I guess until they get to it it might be a few days/weeks/months/years. :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had this happen to my reports as well. The change that triggered it was a part of GA navigation 'upgrade' which messed up the original email PDF template.

I had to **re-create all the scheduled email reports from scratch** in GA and when those come in, they are in the correct format. Try that if it helps.

Comment: "had to re-create" what do you mean, exactly? I tried removing and creating the custom reports, no success.